# Efficient way for generating coprime pairs

Tags: primes, greatest-common-divisor

I need to print the number of coprime pairs (a,b), 0 < a <= b <= n and for n = 10^8 the program should run in less than 10 seconds. I have used this method : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarefreeCouple.html

But the program isn't as fast as I expected. 
I have heard about an effient way of solving this problem by using something called 'Farey Sequence' but the code was written in PHP and I can only understand C.

So which method can help me solve the problem? thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your stated interest is in co-prime pairs (a, b). The carefree couple adds an additional restriction that `a` is square-free. Therefore it is *not* the same problem, though some of the math is similar. As I understand your problem it is equivalent to summing the Euler totient function from 1 to n, the so-called [Totient Summatory Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientSummatoryFunction.html).

I do not know of any tricks that give one a simple closed form solution to come up with the answer. However, I think modifying a straightforward [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (SoT) should get you an answer in much less than 10 seconds in most programming languages.

<s>Normally running the SoT simply yields a list of the primes <= n. Our goal will change, however, to computing the complete prime-power factorization of each integer between 1 and n inclusive. To do that we must store more than a single bit of information for each sieve entry, we must store a list. As we sieve a prime p through the array, we add (p, 1) to the list already stored at that entry. Then we sieve by p<sup>2</sup> and change the (p,1) entries in each location we hit to (p,2), and so one for each power of p <= n and every p <= n. When it finishes, you
can compute the Totient function quickly for every value 0 <= x <= n and sum them up.</s>

EDIT:
I see that there is already a much better set of answers to the question on math.stackexchange.com [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316376/552). I'll leave this answer up for awhile until the disposition of the question is settled.

Comment: I have heard about a recursive way of solving my problem

Comment: S(n)= (n*(n+1) )/2 -Σ{i=2..n}(S(n/i))  where S(x)=sum{i=1..x}(phi(x))